# Can I remove leading zeros in a url in django?

Tags: python, django, .htaccess

Am redirecting urls from a legacy site, which gets me to a url like this:

```
http://example.com/blog/01/detail
```

I would like to automatically *remove the leading zeros* from these urls (seems it doesn't matter how many zeros are in there `001` `0001` `000001` work) so that the page redirects to:

```
http://example.com/blog/1/detail
```

Is there a simple way to go about doing this in django ?  (Or, via the `.htaccess` redirect?)

#### URL code:

```
url(u'^blog/(?P<object_id>\d+)/detail$', 
    list_detail.object_detail,
    { 'queryset' : Blog.objects.all(), },
    name='blog_detail',)
```

#### .htaccess (being redirected):

```
RewriteRule ^blog-([0-9]+) http://example.com/blog/$1 [R=301]
```

Would I need some middleware or is there an easy way to do this in the `urls.py` file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it by eiditing either the urls.py regex or the .htaccess regex:

#### In Django

```
'^blog/0*(?P<object_id>\d+)/detail$'
```

#### In .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^blog-0*([0-9]+) http://example.com/blog/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
url(u'^blog/0*(?P<object_id>\d+)/detail$', 
    list_detail.object_detail,
    { 'queryset' : Blog.objects.all(), },
    name='blog_detail',)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea - but this isn't actually _changing_ the final url by removing the zeros ... the links work, but I want to get rid of all the leading 0s. ... i want to go from 01 to 1 in the url

Comment: making the same change to the .htaccess regex will actually remove the 0's in the url